# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one data frame named **last_df** that has only 1 record.

while I am trying to check the value of a column it gave me the following error:

```
if last_df[last_df['status'] == 'COMPLETE']:
    pass

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

what is the issue over here?

Comment: It doesnt matter how many records you have in the resulting Series. It is still a _Series_ of boolean values. This is like saying `if [False]:` where it's ambiguous, do you mean `bool([False])` which is truthy because it's a collection with (a non-zero number of) elements or are you referring to the boolean values contained in the collection making this False.

Comment: If it has only one record and you want to check that then use `if last_df.iloc[0]['status'] == 'COMPLETE'`. But I feel compelled to ask why use a dataframe if it's going to be one record only?

Comment: @HenryEcker, thanks for the clarification. it is really helpful.

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal, thanks for the code snippet. It's a filtered df.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just looking for the existence of a value in the column you can use

```
'COMPLETE' in last_df.status.values
```

If you want to check all the columns then use df.isin

```
last_df.isin(["COMPLETE"]).any().any()
```